# PXE reliability

Tags: boot, pxe, data-integrity

I understand that PXE is implemented by using TFTP over UDP - neither one of those protocols verifies integrity, which would seem important for something like the operating system - is there some sort integrity check elsewhere prior to the OS booting? is each OS expected to do it's own integrity check first? (This seems like a bad idea) - or is it just not important enough for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PXE is just a part of your "Network Based Provisioning Environment" ...
PXE can be protected today by Secure Boot (UEFI) or in the past by the BIS specification.

The PXE role stops when the last NBP (network boot program) in the boot chain stops using the PXE APIs (Aplication program Interface) from that moment on security must be implemented by the software assembly being booted/deployed.

Today "Network Based Provisioning Environments" like WDS/MDT/SCCM have lot of security features like DHCP MAC & Architecture filters, DOMAIN restrictions, etc etc etc...

Comment: I wasn't asking for the security, rather integrity of it

Comment: the integrity is a consequence of your security

Comment: you do have a point, I suppose I should be more specific with the question.